# IndexOn to count total users in my database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a database with around 7 - 8k users, every time I do `getChildrenCount()` to count how many people is in my app I really have to wait a lot for it to process and come up.

I wonder if there is a way that for example storing a long variable in my database like

```
totalusers = 7561
```

can be updated everytime a new user is added to the root node, so I just query that totalusers and get fast everytime the exact quantity of users

I was thinking on something like this to keep track of my users and just query 1 variable and get the data as fast as possible

```
"rules": {
    "users": {
        ".indexOn": "totalusers"

    }
```

is this a good way to implement this behavior ?

Edit:

this is what I'm doing right now

```
  public long getUsers(DatabaseReference mDatabase){

        mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    users = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                    Log.e(TAG, "onDataChange: "+users);
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

        return users;
    }
```

but this is too slow, like 1 minute to count 7500 users and also my others firebase operations are not executing untill this one finish , so its blocking my UI and not showing nothing

thanks !

Comment: are you using Firebase Authentication to provide the auth system?

Comment: yes, I'm using mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

Comment: Reading the entire users table every time can be [a very bad idea](https://hackernoon.com/how-we-spent-30k-usd-in-firebase-in-less-than-72-hours-307490bd24d)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've found out, Firebase (like many NoSQL databases) doesn't have built-in aggregation operations. So counting the number of user nodes in your database now requires that you download all user nodes, and then count them in your app: quite wasteful in bandwidth if all you need is the count.

A common approach is to store the count as a separate value in the database, and then update that counter with every update to the `users` node. You can do this from client-side code, but nowadays you might also want to consider doing this from Cloud Functions for Firebase. In fact, this use-case is so common that it is one of the examples in the `functions-samples` repo on Github: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count

Btw: Gregorio's answer is also totally valid. I just wanted to show an alternative that is a bit closer to your current approach.

Answer (score 3):

Firebase databases (both, the realtime one and Firestore) are NOSQL databases, and things such as counts do not perform very well on them.

Since you are using Firebase Authentication, you can use a Firebase Function to reach your goal. You can write functions that will run every time something in your Firebase project happens. One of those "things", is the [creation of an user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events). To put it shortly, you can execute your logic every time a new user is created, and update the count of your users through that logic. Here's an example:

```
exports.updateUserCount = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // here goes your logic. You'll update the count here
});
```

So, in this way, you can store the count in the realtime database, or in Firestore. It's up to you to decide where to put the value. Also, you can do the same thing on a user deletion, but registering a function using onDelete() method.

This will be very fast, and you'll have a value that has not to be determined every time you need it. Please, refer to the link below for a complete reference on Firebase Functions

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Comment: Bummer, I was just about to post the exact same solution :)

Comment: what about this code exports.updateUserCount = functions.database.ref('users/{userId}').onCreate(() => {
  return admin.database().ref('userCount').transaction(userCount => (userCount || 0) + 1);
});

Comment: you're not persisting the value of the variable userCount. After you update the value, you have to set that value in the database. Also, why are you triggering the function on the creation of a database value? This could work, but only if somehow you are creating a db entry everytime a user registers to your app

Comment: Thanks so much gregorio !

Comment: Also make the background function idempotent, it may run multiple time for any given instance.